# Query with three join incredibly slow

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, slim

I'm trying to return all the country that have football `matches` which play in a specific `date`. The data are defined in the following tables:

*competition*

```
id | country_id | name 
50       1         Premier League
```

*competition_seasons*

```
id | competition_id | name
 70       50          2019
```

*competition_rounds*

```
id | season_id | name 
 58       70      Regular Season
```

*match*

```
id | round_id | home | away | result | datetime
 44      58       22     87     1 - 0  2019-03-16:00:00
```

There are different competitions stored in the `competition` table, and then each competition can have multiple `season` which are stored in the `competition_seasons`. A `season` can also have different competition `rounds`, these are stored in `competition_rounds`.

All the `matches` are stored in the `match` table and are grouped for the `round_id`.

I wrote this method for the API:

```
$app->get('/country/get_countries/{date}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
  $start_date = $args["date"] . " 00:00";
  $end_date = $args["date"] . " 23:59";

  $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT n.* FROM country n
    LEFT JOIN competition c ON c.country_id = n.id
    LEFT JOIN competition_seasons s ON s.competition_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN `match` m ON m.round_id = r.id
    WHERE m.datetime BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND '" . $end_date . "'
    GROUP BY n.id");

  $sql->execute();
  $countries = $sql->fetchAll();
  return $response->withJson($countries);
});
```

there are thousands of records organized by id, but the query took about 6, 7 seconds to return all the `countries` that play in the specified date.

How can I optimize this process?

**Performance**

[image]

**UPDATE**

I noticed an interesting thing, if I do:

```
SELECT round_id, DATE("2019-03-18") FROM `match`
```

the query is really fast, so I guess the `datetime` field is slow down the join part, any idea about that?

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`competition` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `category` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `id_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_competition_types_competition_type_id_idx` (`category` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_country_competition_country_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`country` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_categories_competition_category_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`competition_categories` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`competition_seasons` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `competition_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `season_id` INT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `update_at` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_competition_competition_seasons_competition_id_idx` (`competition_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_competition_seasons_competition_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`competition_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`competition` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`competition_rounds` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `round_id` INT NULL,
  `season_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_competition_seasons_competition_rounds_season_id_idx` (`season_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_seasons_competition_rounds_season_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`season_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`competition_seasons` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `swp`.`match`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`match` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `round_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `group_id` INT NULL,
  `datetime` DATETIME NULL,
  `status` INT NULL,
  `gameweek` INT NULL,
  `home_team_id` INT NULL,
  `home_team_half_time_score` INT NULL,
  `home_team_score` INT NULL,
  `home_extra_time` INT NULL,
  `home_penalties` INT NULL,
  `away_team_id` INT NULL,
  `away_team_half_time_score` INT NULL,
  `away_team_score` INT NULL,
  `away_extra_time` INT NULL,
  `away_penalties` INT NULL,
  `venue_id` INT NULL,
  `venue_attendance` INT NULL,
  `aggregate_match_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `home_team_id_idx` (`home_team_id` ASC),
  INDEX `away_team_id_idx` (`away_team_id` ASC),
  INDEX `venue_id_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
  INDEX `match_status_id_idx` (`status` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_competition_rounds_match_round_id_idx` (`round_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_match_match_aggregate_match_id_idx` (`aggregate_match_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_competition_groups_match_group_id_idx` (`group_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_match_home_team_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`home_team_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_match_away_team_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`away_team_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_venue_match_venue_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`venue` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_match_status_match_status_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`status`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`match_status` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_rounds_match_round_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`round_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`competition_rounds` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_match_match_aggregate_match_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`aggregate_match_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`match` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_competition_groups_match_group_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`competition_groups` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Why left join instead of inner join? You want records that match all the criteria at once, after all

Comment: Use prepared statements. Do not concatenate strings.

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . How large are the tables (in rows)?  What is the datatype of `datetime`?  Are the data types of the join keys all the same?  You can add this information in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `match` table is 527.1 Mb, `competition_seasons` is 1.8Mb, `competition` is 208 Kib and `competition_rounds` is 4Mb

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . In the explain plan that you posted, the first comparison should be `>=`, not `<=`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff check the update please

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . Something is wrong with the index usage.  Either you don't have an index on `match(datetime, roundid)` or it is not being used for some reason, such as a type conflict.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added here the full table structure: https://pastebin.com/vmhSjZBA

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . I don't see the index that I recommend in my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I almost to fix this, seems like a `datetime` problem, infact if I execute this: `SELECT * FROM `match` m WHERE m.datetime >= "2019-03-18" AND m.datetime < "2019-03-19"` the query is slow, but the other query are fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `LEFT JOIN`, the query can only be executed top-bottom, meaning the last table is scanned for every product of entries in the before tables. Also, using `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY` without any aggregate makes no sense, because it will always return all country ids. This having said, I would rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.country_id
FROM 
    competition c,
WHERE 

    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            competition_seasons s,
            competition_rounds r,
            `match` m
        WHERE
            s.competition_id = c.id
            AND r.season_id = s.id
            AND m.round_id = r.id 
            AND m.datetime BETWEEN ...
    )
```

This will be correctly optimized by all RDB's I know of.
Note, an 2-column index on `(match.datetime, match.round_id)` - in this order, will make a huge performance impact. Or is write speed is a concern, at least a single column index on `(match.datetime)` would be recommended.

**Important note about indexes on strings**: String comparison is always quirky in RDBs. Make sure you use a binary collation for the datetime column or use native DATETIME format. Various RDBs may fail to use indexes on case-insensitive columns.

Note I removed the join on n - that just add another PK lookup to check that the country still exists in the countries table. You can add it back in if you don't have any ON DELETE CASCADE or other kind of constraint that ensures data consistency, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    n.id
FROM 
    country n
WHERE 

    EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            competition c,
            competition_seasons s,
            competition_rounds r,
            `match` m
        WHERE
            c.country_id=n.id
            AND s.competition_id = c.id
            AND r.season_id = s.id
            AND m.round_id = r.id 
            AND m.datetime BETWEEN ...
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately your query is really slow in my database, took about 24 seconds: https://imgur.com/a/1UHCdrT as you can see in my question the field `datetime` is in datetime format

Comment: Can you post the index you added? (SQL or image). Even better, the whole SQL of the table (structure only). Use Export function in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yep, I updated the question, if you see at the bottom I added all the table interested in the query

Comment: So... I don't see any index on datetime.

Comment: Okay, but how can I add index on datetime? This step is not clear for me

Comment: Try `CREATE INDEX dt ON \`swp\`.\`match\` (\`datetime\`,\`match_id\`)` - or use the interface to create an index on these 2 columns, in the same order (do not change column order).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190283/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-dinu).

Answer (score 4):

First, write the query as:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM country n JOIN
     competition c
     ON c.country_id = n.id JOIN
     competition_seasons s
     ON s.competition_id = c.id JOIN
     competition_rounds r
     ON r.season_id = s.id JOIN
     `match` m
     ON m.round_id = r.id
WHERE m.datetime >= ? AND
      m.datetime < ?
GROUP BY n.id;
```

The changes here are relatively minor and will not affect performance.  But they are important:

- `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, because you require that the conditions match.
- Parameters for the date rather than munging the query string, because this is a good idea.
- `>=` and `<` for the comparison, because this works with both dates and date times.  You will need to add 1 day to the end date -- but leave off the time component.

Then, for performance, you want indexes:

- `match(datetime, round_id)`
- `competition_rounds(id, season_id)`
- `competition_seasons(id, competition_id)`
- `competition(id, country_id)`
- `country(id)`

Actually, the first is the most important.  The last four are not needed if the respective `id` columns are declared as primary keys.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I really appreciate that, anyway I can't see any difference about the performance, is there something that I can do?

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . Assuming you have added the indexes, how long do the query take without the `GROUP BY`?  My assumption is that there are just a handful of matches that meet the date condition, so the `GROUP BY` should be cheap.

Comment: if I remove the `GROUP BY` I'll get duplicated country and same performance issue

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . How long does this simple query take and how many rows are returned?  `select count(*) from match m where m.datetime >= ? and m.datetime < ?`

Comment: The query takes about 2.1226 seconds and return 2132 rows: https://imgur.com/a/BzP8Cei

Comment: @sfarzoso . . . That seems like a long time if you have the index `match(datetime, round_id)`.  Perhaps you are just on a really slow computer, are severely memory limited, or there is a lot of load on your computer.

Comment: Could be possible, but other query are quickly.. there are different connection to the database that push data so it's strange that in this specific case I got this problem, what do yuo suggest? The pc have 4 giga or ram and 2 core processor linux based

Comment: @sfarzoso try to execute above SQL with EXPLAIN and post the result here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you explain the part of the performance? I don't understand what I need to do for improve that